# How do I increase the height of the URL bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css

Firefox 47 on Kubuntu 16.  The URL Bar is so tiny it's difficult to read.

If I increase the height of the URL Bar in userChrome.css like so:

```
#urlbar {height: 40px !important}
```

then the URL bar does get bigger, but the bottom cuts off.  I've attached a screencap to show it.[image]

As shown in the screencap, I've also increased the size of the Nav Bar with

```
#nav-bar {height: 100px !important}
```

to accommodate the increased URL Bar, but the URL Bar still cuts off.  How do I get a taller, fully-visible URL Bar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to reposition the urlbar area and its contents:

```
# urlbar-wrapper {
  height: 36px !important; 
  margin-bottom: -12px !important;
}
# urlbar {
  margin-top: -12px !important;
}
```

Definitely not perfect but perhaps good enough for now?